# Unable to set timezone on Xen VM running CentOS 5

Tags: centos

I have a XEN domU running CentOS 5.

I'm having trouble setting the correct timezone.

I want it to run on Mountain Standard Time, but it shows Pacific Standard time.  I've tried everything, but I can't get this right.  This VM doesn't have Internet access, so I can't use ntpd or anything.  I sync it up with another Xen domU running XP, which has the correct timezone and time. But even if I don't sync up, it should show me the correct timezone, since I'm pointing /etc/localtime at the correct timezone.

Here's all the commands (and output for some) I've used so far.

```
# mv /etc/localtime  /etc/localtime-old

# ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Mountain /etc/localtime

# vi /etc/sysconfig/clock

ZONE="America/Denver"
UTC=true
ARC=false

# /usr/sbin/tzdata-update

# /sbin/hwclock --systohc --utc

# uname -a
Linux MyServer 2.6.18-164.6.1.el5 #1 SMP Tue Nov 3 16:18:27 EST 2009 i686 athlon i386 GNU/Linux
```

Now when I type date it shows PST 
    # date
    *Thu Apr  7 16:29:34 PDT 2011*

ntpd is not running

What's missing?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I ended up synching the troubled machine with another machine every minute, just using simple ntpdate command run from a script invoked via crontab every minute.

Comment: seriously, how this can be a good solution?

Answer (score 4):

Do you use a PV Xen DomU? If so, your time is coupled with the Dom0. If you want to change that, do a `sysctl -e xen.independent_wallclock = 1`

After that timezone, ntpdate and ntp will function as expected.

Comment: Oh - that was easy. ;-) So for these points just an additional comment: To make it reboot-safe add
`xen.independent_wallclock = 1` to /etc/sysctl.conf

Answer (score 1):

You do realize that `uname -a` is displaying the date and timezone information from when the kernel was actually built? That changing the timezone settings will not affect the results of `uname -a` timezone display unless you recompile your kernel.

For a domU to run ntpd you will need to set the `xen.independent_wallclock` sysctl value to 1 as Nils mentions but that won't affect the timezone displayed via `uname -a`. Otherwise all the other steps you show as having taken should affect the timezone on your machine and if the results of simply running `date` returns the timezone you're expecting then it is complete and your test of using `uname -a` to verify is all that is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible the TZ environment variable is set for your user?  TZ will override /etc/localtime with a different timezone.  Run "echo $TZ"

Comment: There's no TZ environment variable set.

Comment: I'm not sure, but nscd might cache the timezone info... you might try restarting it.